# How to call functions from multiple cpp from a single lua?

Tags: lua

I'm recently learning lua to write some mod for a game. The developers are not gonna provide some specific container in cpp, so I planned to do it my self. Now I have an implementation in lua, but it's slow. I'm curious is it possible to code in cpp to speed this up.

Cpp(the game) <---> lua(my mod) <---> another cpp(what I planned)

Thanks.

Comment: Does your game allow you to use external binary libraries and load them with `require`?

Comment: It's allowed to require lua file from a lua, but no idea on requiring a cpp or anything else from lua. Actually I haven't learn enough for this. I don't know the detail. The game is Factorio. If it's possible, then I'll spend enough time to pick it up. But some has told me it's not possible, for security concerns. They implemented it in another way with some function provided by the game, which is slow but acceptable. Now I'm curious about, if I would develop a game in the future, is it smart to use lua as the mod api. Thanks.